# Show jQuery sliders result smooth

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

Can someone help me making my slider show the result more smooth.

```
function updateAmounts() {  
  var value1 = $('#slider1').slider('value');  
  $('#amount1').val(value1);  

  var ude1 = 5 * Math.round((value1*3).toFixed(2)/5);
  $('#ude1mdr').val(ude1);  
}
var valueMultiplier = 5;

$('#slider1').slider({value: 0, min: 0, max: 200, step: 1, stop: function(event, ui) {
  updateAmounts();
}});

updateAmounts();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TXc8K/5/

It only shows values when you let go of the mouse. I would like both values to display/change whenever the slider is moved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the event on when you call `updateAmounts();` from stop to slide so that your function will be called every time you slide, not every time you stop (let go of the mouse).

Try:

```
$('#slider1').slider({value: 0, min: 0, max: 200, step: 1, slide: function(event, ui) {
    updateAmounts();//--------------------------------------^ here
}});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TXc8K/9/)